# How can perform to delete all rows within a table in a oracle database, which value = 0 for one of the columns?

Tags: sql, database

basically, it's like this:

The table is called `PH.INVENTORY`, the column name is `ONHANDQUANTITY`

I want to run a query which deletes all rows in `PH.INVENTORY` table in which the `ONHANDQUANTITY` value is 0 (All rows contain  a 0 value for the column `ONHANDQUANTITY`)

how can I add in my delete query?

```
public void Delete(ItemModel Item)
{
    Conn = ORCONN.con;
    if (Conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        Conn.Open();
    }

    try
    {
        cmd.Connection = Conn;

        var query = "DELETE FROM PH.INVENTORY WHERE INVNO LIKE '" + Item.INVNO.Trim() + "%'";


        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        Conn.Close();
    }
}
```

How can i add? this is my sql.

```html
    Updated my code, is it right??

                    var query = "DELETE FROM PH.INVENTORY WHERE INVNO LIKE '" + Item.INVNO.Trim() + "%'";

                    var queryto  = "DELETE FROM PH.INVENTORY WHERE ONHANDQTY = 0 ";

                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Conn.Close();
                }
```

Comment: The method you shared deletes rows from table based on `LIKE` criteria on column `INVNO`. Do you want to add extra condition for ONHANDQUANTITY colum in existing DELETE query? Or you want to have separate delete operation for that?

Comment: I want to separate deletion of my onhandquantity, inside of this code

Comment: **Sidenote** - always use prepared statement instead of plain string concatenation

Answer (score 1):

> I want to run a query which deletes all rows in PH.INVENTORY table in
>   which the ONHANDQUANTITY value is 0

The query is:

```
delete from ph.inventory
    where onhandquantity = 0;
```

I don't know what this has to do with the sample code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
  ONHANDQUANTITY = 0 and
```

Between the words "where" and "inv0" in the query string.